# Online file comparison tool

Tags: python, diff, compare

I want to a visualize web file compare tool,that can embed into my app,I know there some software like beyond compare,it has done great job,but it on windows & need buy licence,if someone has develop a web version,then it can cross platform,

does some already achieve this?

if it is python - friendly is great appreciated

Comment: Have you considered [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i want a web version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at rietveld
http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/

Here is an example http://codereview.appspot.com/2208048/diff/4001/Documentation/notation/fretted-strings.itely

Answer (score 1):

There is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/): *Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software development projects. ... It provides an interface to  Subversion (or other version control systems)...*

It is written in python, and can compare source files. This looks like:

http://trac.edgewall.org/changeset?old_path=%2Ftrunk%2Ftrac%2Fdb%2Fschema.py&old=7890&new_path=%2Ftrunk%2Ftrac%2Fdb%2Fschema.py&new=9406

Comment: this is great,i didn't check the source code yet,and i want know dose it easy extract the core compare file code,i doubt it depent on svn deeply,both trac & rietveld are code review tools,what exactly i want is a tool like winmerge compare file,change file,then save file,that't all,but these two app is very suit for prototype